# Pi can not ping/access devices in local network, but finds them through ARP

Tags: raspbian, pi-2

My Raspberry Pi (Running Raspbian 8 jessie) can not ping devices inside my local network anymore.
It is connected via Wlan0, where as other devices are connected with the router through eth0.

Pi has the IP of `192.168.0.58` inside the network.
Second PC has the IP of `192.168.0.6`.
The PC can SSH and ping the Pi flawlessyly.
The Pi however can not ping the PC (`ping 192.168.0.6`). It simply hangs there, doing nothing.

Issuing `arp -a` from the Pi reveals the PC and its IP address.

If you need any more information feel free to request. Other than that, thanks in advance!

// The requested outputs:

### /etc/network/interfaces

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

### /etc/dhcpd.conf

```
# A sample configuration for dhcpcd.
# See dhcpcd.conf(5) for details.

# Allow users of this group to interact with dhcpcd via the control socket.
#controlgroup wheel

# Inform the DHCP server of our hostname for DDNS.
hostname

# Use the hardware address of the interface for the Client ID.
clientid
# or
# Use the same DUID + IAID as set in DHCPv6 for DHCPv4 ClientID as per RFC4361.
#duid

# Persist interface configuration when dhcpcd exits.
persistent

# Rapid commit support.
# Safe to enable by default because it requires the equivalent option set
# on the server to actually work.
option rapid_commit

# A list of options to request from the DHCP server.
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option classless_static_routes
# Most distributions have NTP support.
option ntp_servers
# Respect the network MTU.
# Some interface drivers reset when changing the MTU so disabled by default.
#option interface_mtu

# A ServerID is required by RFC2131.
require dhcp_server_identifier

# Generate Stable Private IPv6 Addresses instead of hardware based ones
slaac private

# A hook script is provided to lookup the hostname if not set by the DHCP
# server, but it should not be run by default.
nohook lookup-hostname
```

### `sudo ip addr`

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:a0:b5:2d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::b957:cdb3:7379:44ec/64 scope link tentative
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ac:a2:13:38:85:7c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.58/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global wlan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2a02:8108:100:1a10:9e31:a828:54aa:fcd2/64 scope global noprefixroute dynamic
       valid_lft 5037sec preferred_lft 2337sec
    inet6 fe80::db3:97c8:79bb:fab7/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: *"It simply hangs there, doing nothing."* -> Likely either the Pi is not having traffic initiated by it routed because it does not actually have a lease (this can happen, e.g., if you arbitrarily assign it a static IP, in which case traffic addressed to that will proliferate through the network, giving the Pi an opportunity to respond), and the router is instead silently dropping the packets, or else the PC's firewall is silently dropping packets.

Comment: You might want to have a look at what is going on using a tool like [wireshark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark), although it involves a bit of an initial learning curve it is not super difficult.  If both machines are attached to the router via ethernet or open wifi you should be able to see all relevant traffic running it on just one of them; if they are on encrypted wifi you will have to run it both, or disconnect and reconnect the one while the other is actively monitoring.

Comment: What does the route table look like, and what does tcpdump say?

Comment: Since you have not mentioned what OS the PC is running, you might want to read [this](http://superuser.com/questions/627208/unable-to-ping-a-windows-machine-from-linux) in case it is running Windows.

Comment: You were right, W10 firewall caused the issue. I only wonder why it worked like 30 minutes prior to this post :/